# finding if two binary quadratic forms represent the same integers

Tags: algorithms, quadratic-forms

I am currently working with quadratic forms for a given discriminant D;
to get all primitive forms (one for each equivalence class) I found this website : http://www.numbertheory.org/php/classnoneg.html

For instance for the case D=-23, the three primitive forms are given by :
(1,1,6), (2,1,3), (2,-1,3); and I know that the two last ones represent the same integers.

I need now to work with some discriminant such that the class number is larger (h(D)=4,5..) and I need to know if two forms represent the same integers.
Would you know of a similar software where I can check this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: most of what a beginner might need to know is in the first chapter of David A. Cox, *Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2,$* which is still in print. I got more information, especially about Gauss composition, Pell equations, and how to write correct computer programs for everything, in Duncan A. Buell, *Binary Quadratic Forms*. Similar to this is *Binary Quadratic Forms* by  J. Buchmann and U. Vollmer, although it strikes me as being a little harder to read; it is still in print though. My favorite, Buell, is available used but perhaps a bit pricey.

The bad news is that this is pretty much solved by [VOIGHT](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/research.html), item number 6, which appeared in Math. Comp. about 2007.

On the other hand, you are welcome to my C++ program for this, sample output below. As you can see, the program finds the whole class group and then finds the principal genus ("squares"). I can usually figure out the other genera myself, and always can if there are just one or two genera. Hmmm...I also have programs that show me the numbers represented by a positive form, up to a bound I type in, different program for just primes, third program for primitively represented numbers.

---

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./classGroup
Absolute value of discriminant? 
56
  class  number  4

 all  
( 1, 0, 14)
( 2, 0, 7)
( 3, -2, 5)
( 3, 2, 5)

 squares  
( 1, 0, 14)
( 2, 0, 7)

 fourths  
( 1, 0, 14)


Discriminant        -56     h :    4     Squares :    2     Fourths :    1
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

---

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./classGroup
Absolute value of discriminant? 
47
  class  number  5

 all  
( 1, 1, 12)
( 2, -1, 6)
( 2, 1, 6)
( 3, -1, 4)
( 3, 1, 4)

 squares  
( 1, 1, 12)
( 2, -1, 6)
( 2, 1, 6)
( 3, -1, 4)
( 3, 1, 4)

 fourths  
( 1, 1, 12)
( 2, -1, 6)
( 2, 1, 6)
( 3, -1, 4)
( 3, 1, 4)


Discriminant        -47     h :    5     Squares :    5     Fourths :    5
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

---

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer, Will.                       I am quite new to binary quadratic forms; but I thought forms in the same genus would not necessarily represent the same integers:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_of_a_quadratic_form
                                                                                 How should I interpret the "squares" and "fourths"? In your first example, the two last forms seem to represent the same integers, is it why they are discarded on the second round?                                          Last question: where could I get your C++ program?

Comment: @saradi, for the program(s) you would need to email me, the gmail address is more suitable...the class group is a finite abelian group, the squares make up the principal genus, any genus is a coset of that in the class group. I recommend Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms, because he explains the facts as well as shows you how to compute things. Also Cox, Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2.$ The fourth powers make up the "spinor kernel," most people do not need to know what that is. Oh, $(3, \pm 2, 5)$ are not squares in the class group, they are in the other genus.